# Can I disable the creation of _middlewareManifest.js in NextJS?

Tags: next.js, middleware

I am not using any middleware in NextJS but yet there still is a `_middlewareManifest.js` with `self.__MIDDLEWARE_MANIFEST=[];self.__MIDDLEWARE_MANIFEST_CB&&self.__MIDDLEWARE_MANIFEST_CB()` in it.

Can I disable the generation and inclusion of this file in some way?